# Using **kwargs for multiple file upload

Tags: python

I have written a code as follows that takes in different inputs in the `__init__` of the class and functions that come afterwards use the key arguments for a certain process (I have brought an example here but the original code has more functions and more files to process).

```
import os
from config import data_directory #directory where the datasets are located
import pandas as pd

class Analysis(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.data1 = kwargs.get('data1')
        self.data2 = kwargs.get('data1')
    def analysis1(self):
        print(self.data1['col1'],
              self.data2['col1'])
    def analysis2(self):
        print(self.data2['col3'])

def analyzing():
    tobeanalyzed = Analysis()
    tobeanalyzed.analysis1()
    tobeanalyzed.analysis2()

return tobeanalyzed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    analyzing(data1 =pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_directory , 'file1.csv'), na_filter = False), 
       data2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_directory , 'file2.csv'), na_filter = False))
```

I guess there is something wrong with the way I have defined the data1 and data2 but do not know how to correct it.

Error:

```
TypeError: analyzing() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data1'
```

Comment: You create `Analysis` with no parameters. That should give you `data1` and `data2` with `None` values. When you call `analysis1` or `analysis2` it tries to look up `'col1'` etc as keys in the non-existent dictionaries.

Comment: What error do you get? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I assume there is some missing indentation after the `def analyzing():`?  This currently isn't runnable.  Also, can you provide some very simple examples for `file1` and `file2`?  Also, what is the error you get when running this (with full traceback please)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow `**kwargs` on the `analyzing` function as well and pass them on to the `Analysis` constructor:

```py
import os
from config import data_directory #directory where the datasets are located
import pandas as pd

class Analysis(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.data1 = kwargs.get('data1')
        self.data2 = kwargs.get('data1')
    def analysis1(self):
        print(self.data1['col1'],
              self.data2['col1'])
    def analysis2(self):
        print(self.data2['col3'])

def analyzing(**kwargs):
    tobeanalyzed = Analysis(**kwargs)
    tobeanalyzed.analysis1()
    tobeanalyzed.analysis2()

    return tobeanalyzed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    analyzing(data1 =pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_directory , 'file1.csv'), na_filter = False), 
       data2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_directory , 'file2.csv'), na_filter = False))
```